# Multiply a floating point number by 2

Tags: floating-point

Can someone please take me through the steps of how to multiply any single precision floating point number by 2? or any other constant for that matter. The math/steps confuse me a little. I am aware that I can use <<1 to multiply by 2 for an int but the I don't know where to start for a fp number.

Thanks!

Comment: Typically we multiply (*) it by two (2). What is your problem? What else are you going to achieve? Are you trying to find a faster way? If so, then you can typically lave the optmization to the compiler. A good compiler will - for int - convert a multplication with the constant 2 into a shift left 1. Als a programmer - these days, unlike 60s and 70s - yo don' t need to bother.

Comment: we might need more information, like language and purpose. because right now just *2 seems like the answer, but i highly doubt you didn't know multiply is *.. so what is the actual question? please reelaborate

Comment: *(float)2 if it is java

Comment: Well, if your problem is, as @SumodhS suggests, that your compiler takes 2 as an int, then you can cast it or use 2.0 or 2f or 2.0f instead. For more details about this you should tell us which programming language you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, I am trying to find a way to multiply by a constant by manipulating the bits with just the bitwise operators and without casing. I know I have to use << for an int. I am confused as to how to go about it for a fp number

Comment: Contrary to your belief, there is no *need* to use a shift to multiply by 2 (or a power of 2), plain multiply (* 2) is fine. The shift trick was useful in the old days, when the processor ALUs didn't integrate a fast multiplier. [Division by 2 is another story.] Shifting is irrelevant for the floating-point representation as the mantissas are normalized. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maybe asking for a hack to quickly multiply by 2 ?

You can increment the exponent field in the FP representation, assuming IEEE format (bits 23-30).

But

- this isn't portable,
- requires bit-field manipulation,
- won't work for special numbers like 0 or denormalized.

---

You can achieve the same effect with portable calls, like

```
x= ldexp(frexp(x, &e), e + 1);
```

but one can fear that function overhead kills any benefit.